# Capture email content

Tags: .net, email, smtp

Does someone know how can i (using .net) capture the content of any incoming or outgoing email from all the free email providers?

Comment: Are you only tracking one particular incoming email address?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Capture sounds a lot like intercept which is a tad hackish. There are likely security measures in place to prevent such things, if that is what you intend to do. If you're wanting to simply read your email, then look into setting up an email client like Thunderbird.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what you're targeting exactly.  If you're just looking for non-web-based email traffic running across the local machine, then you simply monitor the ports you're looking for (IMAP, POP, SMTP, etc) with a library like libpcap (or SharpPcap for .NET maybe).  You'll probably need to parse the contents of the messages to get what you're looking for, but that's not too tough.

With some more information on what you're trying to do exactly, I might better be able to help you.

Comment: I appreciate your help very much.
I need to be able to Capture all the emails from gmail, hotmail, yahoo, aol......
I also need to be able to capture all IM messages from yahoo, msn, icq messengers.
In other words i need a Real good sniffer.

Thanks.

Comment: Ah, so you do need to capture web-based email then?  This will be browser dependent as well, then.  Is there a particular one your clients will be using?